# How to get authentication with Hostname from another domain

Tags: iis, iis-7, dns, hostname

Having an issue with users of one domain from viewing a website being hosting on another domain.  Both domains are internal, domain1.local & domain2.local.

The website hostname is webapp.domain1.local.  It is being hosted on a server webserver.domain2.local.  When i view the site off the "Default Web Site" as a sub-webapp, it renders correctly when a user, `domain2\user`, is accessing the "Default Web Site" it renders correctly.  But if the same user were to access the `webapp` web site, with hostname `webapp.domain.local`, there is an access denied.

Default Web Site:

- Hostname: localhost default for IIS 7.

`webapp` Web Site:

- Hostname: `webapp.domain1.local`

Both IIS 7 websites having a webapplication named `webapp`.

According to our Network Administrator, there is an existing passthrough communication handle but seems to be quirky on what gets passed through.

#### Background

Over the last 5-7 years the company has been absorbing other smaller companies and during this time absorbed a company as big as them and hence the two domains.  We are currently in the process of migrating to `domain1.local` but its taking time cause of the sheer size of `domain2.local`.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to say without Event Viewer and/or IIS logs from the troublesome server (in either direction) however it looks to me like passthrough is probably doing what it should and denying access because the users are not allowed to authenticate.

I would say your looking at setting up cross domain authentication in its entity e.g. file shares from one domain to another how does that work? If the problem is more wide spread then really your looking at setting up a domain trust relationship between Domain1 and Domain2 ([http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc739693(v=ws.10).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc739693%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)) either this or allow anonymous access to the website but its not exactly secure :)

Any questions let me know.

Charles

Comment: Yeah the two domain forests already have a handshaking protocol designed for the communication but seems that some consumption's of the cross-domain communication are failing.  The Server is on `domain2.local` while the hostname is referencing `domain1.local` CNAME.

Comment: Sorry to sound like one of 'those people' :) but could you elaborate on 'handshaking protocol designed for the communication'?

Comment: that is out of my area of expertise, i know it works cause i can login to servers on both domains, my id is on `domain2.local`.  The more i think about it, could it be that i need to edit the `hosts` file to account for the fact the server is on `domain2.local` but the CNAME record is on `domain1.local`?

Comment: Well I mean when you log on to either Server can you use domain1\username and domain2\username because if your purely just writing your username and password it could be that there are just two accounts one on each domain. When you launch the webapp its using FQDN correct so you load webapp.domain1.local and you try to authenticate using domain2\username.... the problem is it maybe passing your domain2\username credentials to domain1 Domain Controller which of course will fail!...!...

Comment: What you need to make sure is that your Domain Controllers in each domain can 'see' each other say right well if someone from Domain2 is trying to authenticate then using my trust relationship do I allow users from Domain2 to have these access rights. If you simply just have two domains on the same network or within network reach of each other (such as site to site VPN) and not 'trusting' each other then it will fail. Hope this makes sense and helps, its a big subject for discussion across this site.

Comment: Then why would i be able to login to `server.domain1.local` with credentials `domain2.local\userid`?

Comment: Ah ok so you can log in using the correct cross domain authentication. That says to me that external trust is setup. The next part to figure out is what does that trust entitle users to access. So what I would do is try to add windows saved credentials from Control Panel > Users (stored user names and passwords) this changes location from windows version to version. Try adding webapp.domain1.local using domain1\username and then domain2\username that way it should try those credentials instead of passthrough, if you still get access denied with domain2\username then its most likely permissions

Comment: Ok, ill ask our net admin and see what he says.

Comment: Found that the problem was the Authentication on the website.  I had enabled ASP.NET Impersonation & Windows Authentication.  Disabled ASP.NET Impersonation and bam it worked.